# How to ssh to a hidden service with torsocks

Tags: onion-services, ssh, torsocks

How do I ssh to a hidden service with `torsocks`? Manual for `torsocks` says that [ssh should work just fine](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torsocks.git/tree/README.md#n45) yet it doesn't. It fails with the following:

```
$ torsocks ssh username@example.onion
get_sock_port: getnameinfo NI_NUMERICSERV failed: ai_family not supported
```

[Complete debugging log here.](https://gist.github.com/sanmai/3401d567b6510fa830f4)

Is it even remotely possible to use `torsocks` in this case?

---

Sure, if I add an explicit proxy definition to the `.ssh/config`, ssh to this host works just fine, but I'd prefer to use `torsocks` because I not always can or want to modify `.ssh/config` like follows.

```
Host *.onion
    ProxyCommand /bin/nc.openbsd -xlocalhost:9050 -X5 %h %p
```

But that's **not** what I want.

Comment: I tried your command and it works with torsocks 2.1.0 perfectly fine. Thatswhy I'll close the question.

Comment: @JensKubieziel on the same version it gives me this: `torsocks ssh user@host.onion` 
`WARNING torsocks[17541]: [connect] Connection to a local address are denied since it might be a TCP DNS query to a local DNS server. Rejecting it for safety reasons. (in tsocks_connect() at connect.c:186)`

Comment: `"WARNING torsocks[17541]: [connect] Connection to a local address are denied since it might be a TCP DNS query to a local DNS server. Rejecting it for safety reasons."` this is happening because you've probably still got ssh configured to use `nc` to proxy, causing a conflict. do you have any other options set, like are you trying to forward ports or X11?

Comment: @canonizingironize check the debug log - nc isn't used

Comment: sure the debug log it isn't, but that specific error is that it's trying to connect to a localhost address and being denied.

Comment: @canonizingironize denied by what? apparently it's just works now... With or without nc.

Comment: By torsocks, it hooks certain libc calls and blocks them on the basis that they can't be safely performed without possibly leaking.